# How to pass double pointer to COM from C# and initliaze it inside COM

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, intptr

I have crated a COM method which takes double pointer (BYTE**). Inside COM I am allocating memory and initializing it.

Signature is;

```
HRESULT Canny([in] BSTR szLogoPath, [out] BYTE** pBuffer, [out] USHORT* iBufLen);
```

Issue is COM crashes when I call it from a C# project whereas it works fine when I call it from WIN32 project.

Also, in C# project above method is appearing as; (BYTE** is appearing as IntPtr)

```
public virtual void Canny(string szLogoPath,IntPtr pBuffer, out ushort iBufLen);
```

My C# code is

```
LogoFinderClass libCOM = new LogoFinderClass();
unsafe  {
    byte* buf = null;
    IntPtr interopPtr = new IntPtr(&buf); 
    libCOM.Canny(@"..\Logo.bmp", interopPtr, out bufLen);
}
```

In C++ I am allocating memory as;

```
::Canny(BSTR szLogoPath, BYTE** pBuffer, USHORT* iBufLen) {
    *pBuffer = new BYTE[1024]; 
    .. 
}
```

And when calling from C#, COM crashes when allocating memory.

Comment: Using the *new* operator is always wrong in COM interop.  The client code has no hope of calling the proper *delete* operator, CoTaskMemAlloc is required.  If it crashes quickly then you are likely to corrupt the heap.  1024 bytes sounds way too low for an image processing operation like Canny.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I am now using CoTaskMemAlloc () and it's working fine, but Marshal.Copy(..) is not copying the number of bytes which I am allocating inside COM, like I am allocating 8000 bytes but it's copying some 5000 bytes, I think IntPtr is corrupting somewhere. **Yes 1024 is two low for canny operation I have just mentioned it as dummy value**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing byte array between C++ and C# ByRef raises AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862983/passing-byte-array-between-c-and-c-sharp-byref-raises-accessviolationexception)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `unsafe` here. You do need to change the declaration of the function at the C# end. The buffer parameter needs to be declared as:

```
ref IntPtr pBuffer
```

Then, once you've called the function, read out the content of the buffer with `Marshal.Copy`.

I'm not an export on consuming COM from C#, but shouldn't the first parameter have `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]`?

As a further aside, if you use `CoTaskMemAlloc` instead of `new`, you could let the caller deallocate the buffer rather than having to export a deallocator. I trust that you did export a deallocator?

Comment: Thanks @David for reply.

Please could you tell me how can I edit function declaration at the C# end, because lib (COM) under reference filter in solution explorer is not exposing any property to edit its signatures.

Comment: @SKAR As I said, I'm not expert on COM from C#. So, I don't know the specifics in VS. Sorry. But surely there must be C# source code somewhere that declares the interface?

Comment: Thanks @David, COM is not crashing when allocating memory using CoTaskMemAlloc(..), but Marshal.Copy(..) is not copying the number of bytes which I am allocating inside COM, like I am allocating 8000 bytes but it's copying some 5000 bytes, I think IntPtr is corrupting somewhere. But again it's working fine when calling from WIN32 :(

Comment: @SKAR There's no problem using `new[]`. That won't cause a crash. It just forces you to export a deallocator. As for the rest of your comment, sounds like you have a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @David, please could you refer an example?